# Why Iframe is not loading properly in Headless mode of Cypress test runner, but loading properly in interactive mode?

Tags: cypress

I am using command line execution on CI build agents. Same is the case when i run the commandline tests on local machine.
I have already set webchromesecurity = false in cypress.json

[image]

Should be displayed as below:-
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the React iframe not supported in Electron browser.
Set the chrome browser using command --browser chrome in package.json file